# Tenho 5 threads executando paralelamente. Como faço para saber quando todas acabaram?

Tags: java, android, thread

Se eu fizer um `join` para cada uma delas, elas vão executar em sequência, uma por vez. Eu precisava iniciar as 5 paralelamente e saber quando todas acabaram para fazer algo. Alguém sabe se e como é possível? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 5):

Talvez o que você queira seja algo assim:

```java
public class Main {

    private static Thread criarThread(final int numero) {
        return new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("t" + numero + " começou");
                    Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 10000));
                    System.out.println("t" + numero + " terminou");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Ignora...
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread[] ts = {
            criarThread(1),
            criarThread(2),
            criarThread(3),
            criarThread(4),
            criarThread(5)
        };
        for (Thread t : ts) {
            t.start();
        }
        for (Thread t : ts) {
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Ignora...
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Todas as threads terminaram");
    }
}
```

Observe uma das saídas que obtive:

```
t1 começou
t2 começou
t3 começou
t4 começou
t5 começou
t4 terminou
t1 terminou
t3 terminou
t5 terminou
t2 terminou
Todas as threads terminaram
```

Observe que as 5 thread são começadas em paralelo na thread principal e a thread principal dá o `join` nas 5 threads. Desta forma, somente quando as 5 tiverem sido finalizadas, é que a thread principal prossegue.

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/JywMnn)

Comment: Não conhecia esse ideone. Muito bom!

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do @Victor, apesar de correcta, bloqueia a *thread* principal que, no caso do Android, não é aconselhável.

A solução passa por criar uma thread para executar os joins:

```
public class Main {

    private static Thread criarThread(final int numero) {
        return new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("t" + numero + " começou");
                    Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 10000));
                    System.out.println("t" + numero + " terminou");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Ignora...
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread[] ts = {
            criarThread(1),
            criarThread(2),
            criarThread(3),
            criarThread(4),
            criarThread(5)
        };
        for (Thread t : ts) {
            t.start();
        }

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (Thread t : ts) {
                    try {
                        t.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Ignora...
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Todas as threads terminaram");
            }
        }).start();
        System.out.println("A main está livre");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> t1 começou
> t2 começou
> t3 começou
> t4 começou
> t5 começou
> A main está livre
> t3 terminou
> t5 terminou
> t1 terminou
> t4 terminou
> t2 terminou
> Todas as threads terminaram

Veja a funcionar no [ideone](http://ideone.com/DDVOrG)

Comment: Muito pertinente a observação de não bloquear a thread principal.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o método `getAllStackTraces()` da própria classe `Thread` para isso:

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
```

Para converter em um array de `Threads`:

```
Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);
```

Ou, você também pode armazenar em um `int` o número de `Threads` ativas:

```
int quantidadeDeThreads =  Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().size();
```